# Reading a txt file into a dictionary

Tags: python, file, dictionary, key, key-value

I have a text file like such:

```
Ben
5 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 -3 5 0 0 0 5 5 0 0 0 0 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 3 0 1 0 -5 0 0 5 5 0 5 5 5 0 5 5 0 0 0 5 5 5 5 -5 
Moose
5 5 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 1 0 5 3 0 5 0 3 3 5 0 0 0 0 0 5 0 0 0 0 0 3 5 0 0 0 0 0 5 -3 0 0 0 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 5 5 0 3 0 0 
Reuven
5 -5 0 0 0 0 -3 -5 0 1 -5 5 0 1 0 1 -3 1 -5 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 0 -5 1 0 1 0 -5 0 3 -3 3 0 1 5 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 3 1 5 1 3
```

I need to turn this txt file into a dictionary where every other row is the key to the row after it.
Example:

```
d = {'ben': 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 -3 5 0 0 0 5 5 0 0 0 0 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 3 0 1 0 -5 0 0 5 5 0 5 5 5 0 5 5 0 0 0 5 5 5 5 -5, 
"moose":5 5 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 1 0 5 3 0 5 0 3 3 5 0 0 0 0 0 5 0 0 0 0 0 3 5 0 0 0 0 0 5 -3 0 0 0 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 5 5 0 3 0 0, 
"Reuven":5 -5 0 0 0 0 -3 -5 0 1 -5 5 0 1 0 1 -3 1 -5 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 0 -5 1 0 1 0 -5 0 3 -3 3 0 1 5 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 3 1 5 1 3}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! The output isn't valid syntax and I don't see an attempt. Where are you stuck and what is your question? Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: I am just confused on how to get my first row ("Ben") to be the key for the row underneath it and so on. I need All the names in my file to be the keys for the numerical values below them.

Comment: @DylandeHoyos--as mentioned your output is invalid syntax.  Do you want the numbers as a 1) string i.e. '5 0 0 ...' or 2) list i.e. [5, 0, 0, ...]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following way to get what you want

How this works

`enumerate` gives you a (index, value) pair for each iteration, you can directly iterate through every line in a file using the file object `f`. By this way at no point in time will you have to read the entire file into your memory if that concerns you.

`i % 2 == 0` indicates the line is an even line and hence will be a key in your dictionary. The else part will then use this key to add the odd number line.

You can change `line.strip().split()` to just `line` if you dont want a list there.

```
f = open('file.txt')

res = {}

for i, line in enumerate(f):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        key = line.strip()
    else:
        res[key] = line.strip().split()

print(res)
f.close()
```

Output

```
{'Ben': ['5', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '-3', '5', '0', '0', '0', '5', '5', '0', '0', '0', '0', '5', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '3', '0', '1', '0', '-5', '0', '0', '5', '5', '0', '5', '5', '5', '0', '5', '5', '0', '0', '0', '5', '5', '5', '5', '-5'], 'Moose': ['5', '5', '0', '0', '0', '0', '3', '0', '0', '1', '0', '5', '3', '0', '5', '0', '3', '3', '5', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '5', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '3', '5', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '5', '-3', '0', '0', '0', '5', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '5', '5', '0', '3', '0', '0'], 'Reuven': ['5', '-5', '0', '0', '0', '0', '-3', '-5', '0', '1', '-5', '5', '0', '1', '0', '1', '-3', '1', '-5', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '3', '0', '0', '0', '0', '-5', '1', '0', '1', '0', '-5', '0', '3', '-3', '3', '0', '1', '5', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '3', '1', '5', '1', '3']}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

```
with open('input.txt', 'r') as infile:
    data = infile.readlines()   # data is a list with lines of file
    # Use slicing and zip with dictionary comprehension
    # data[::2] are even lines of data
    # data[1::2] are odd lines of data
    # use rstrip to get rid of trailing '\n'
    result = {x.rstrip():y.rstrip() for x, y in zip(data[0::2], data[1::2])}
```

**result contains**

```
{'Ben': '5 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 -3 5 0 0 0 5 5 0 0 0 0 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 3 0 1 0 -5 0 0 5 5 0 5 5 5 0 5 5 0 0 0 5 5 5 5 -5',
 'Moose': '5 5 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 1 0 5 3 0 5 0 3 3 5 0 0 0 0 0 5 0 0 0 0 0 3 5 0 0 0 0 0 5 -3 0 0 0 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 5 5 0 3 0 0',
 'Reuven': '5 -5 0 0 0 0 -3 -5 0 1 -5 5 0 1 0 1 -3 1 -5 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 0 -5 1 0 1 0 -5 0 3 -3 3 0 1 5 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 3 1 5 1 3'}
```

Comment: those slices will create lists in memory, wont they?

Comment: @python_user--yes temporarily, but garbage collected when the result is completed.  Are you wondering about the max file size this can handle?

Comment: yeah, just curious

Comment: @python_user--actually what I said was only partially true.  Slicing does not create copies of the objects in the list, just references to the objects.  S in this case although we may have very long strings i.e. '5 0 0 ...', slicing does not create copies of these strings, just references to them.